# JQUERY add row to table

Tags: jquery

I know how to add row in the table.
But on this given website http://www.javascriptbook.com/code/c12/sort-table.html

```js
var compare = {                           // Declare compare object
  name: function(a, b) {                  // Add a method called name
    a = a.replace(/^the /i, '');          // Remove The from start of parameter
    b = b.replace(/^the /i, '');          // Remove The from start of parameter

    if (a < b) {                          // If value a is less than value b
      return -1;                          // Return -1
    } else {                              // Otherwise
      return a > b ? 1 : 0;               // If a is greater than b return 1 OR
    }                                     // if they are the same return 0
  },
  duration: function(a, b) {              // Add a method called duration
    a = a.split(':');                     // Split the time at the colon
    b = b.split(':');                     // Split the time at the colon

    a = Number(a[0]) * 60 + Number(a[1]); // Convert the time to seconds
    b = Number(b[0]) * 60 + Number(b[1]); // Convert the time to seconds

    return a - b;                         // Return a minus b
  },
  date: function(a, b) {                  // Add a method called date
    a = new Date(a);                      // New Date object to hold the date
    b = new Date(b);                      // New Date object to hold the date

    return a - b;                         // Return a minus b
  }
};

$('.sortable').each(function() {
  var $table = $(this);                     // This sortable table
  var $tbody = $table.find('tbody');        // Store table body
  var $controls = $table.find('th');        // Store table headers
  var rows = $tbody.find('tr').toArray();   // Store array containing rows

  $controls.on('click', function() {        // When user clicks on a header
    var $header = $(this);                  // Get the header
    var order = $header.data('sort');       // Get value of data-sort attribute
    var column;                             // Declare variable called column

    // If selected item has ascending or descending class, reverse contents
    if ($header.is('.ascending') || $header.is('.descending')) {  
      $header.toggleClass('ascending descending');    // Toggle to other class
      $tbody.append(rows.reverse());                // Reverse the array
    } else {                                        // Otherwise perform a sort                            
      $header.addClass('ascending');                // Add class to header
      // Remove asc or desc from all other headers
      $header.siblings().removeClass('ascending descending'); 
      if (compare.hasOwnProperty(order)) {  // If compare object has method
        column = $controls.index(this);         // Search for column’s index no

        rows.sort(function(a, b) {               // Call sort() on rows array
          a = $(a).find('td').eq(column).text(); // Get text of column in row a
          b = $(b).find('td').eq(column).text(); // Get text of column in row b
          return compare[order](a, b);           // Call compare method
        });

        $tbody.append(rows);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

i dont understand why it wont keep adding the same content to the tbody and I have try in the console to  append the new content  to the tbody and it add a extra row everytime.
Any reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add these rows into the table because it has already added in.

First of all, your rows variable will store the reference (not copy the value) to array of tr nodes which has already added in the table. The append function here do not work as expected because it has checked your rows which has already been the children of tbody. Therefor, you need to clone your rows to new objects as follows:

```
 var rows = $tbody.find('tr').clone().toArray();
```

Instead of

```
 var rows = $tbody.find('tr').toArray();
```

Comment: ok , so the same reference cannot be added twice to the table, however, if we make a copy then we can add the same content to the table ?

Comment: That's right. DOM do not care about the content of your tables, it just check your nodes which in this case is your tr nodes, and the same nodes which has been the childrent of a parent node can not be added to it's parent again.